# Connecting 2 monitors to my lap top, best options

Tags: laptop, hdmi, multiple-monitors, display-port

I have a lap top [Asus ROG](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1398352-REG/asus_gl703gm_ds74_17_3_republic_of_gamers.html) and these 2 [LG monitors](https://www.lg.com/rs/monitori/lg-27gn850-b) and I'm trying to connect them in the best possible way. If I'm not mistaken, since my lap top can only go to 120Hz, I assume I can't use the whole potential of the monitors(144Hz), but you can correct me if I'm wrong. My lap top has 1 HDMI 1.4, 1 mini Display Port and 1 USB-C slot. So, I was thinking, mini display port to display port from my lap top to a Display Port splitter, and from the splitter,2 display port to display port cables from the splitter to my monitors. Is that the best way to use the most out of the monitors refresh rate on my lap top or is there a better solution to this? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You cannot split video [unless all you need is a duplicate image on each screen]. Each must have its own port unless it is capable of daisy-chaining, which requires DisplayPort 1.4 [which the displays have, but only one port, so no chaining] or USB 3.1 Gen2 [which the computer has.]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you have to use splitters. You can use a Mini DP to DP adapter to connect one monitor, and connect the other one over HDMI. On the one connected over DP, you should be able to get 144hz, the refresh rate of external monitors is not bound to the refresh rate of your laptop monitor. On the one connected over HDMI, you may only be able to do 60hz because of the bandwidth limitations of HDMI 1.4.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Two more questions. Is there a specific mini DP to DP cable I should use? Those ones that go up to 8k or something else? Is it possible to make them both work at 144hz with a splitter or no?

Comment: I don't know what kinda refresh rate you will get with a splitter, but probably not a lot more than 90hz

Comment: For the miniDP to DP, you can use any cable that is verefied for DP 1.4

Comment: Thanks for the help, at least one of my monitor is working on 144hz, the HDMI one is working on 100Hz, which is fine. Another issue is that my fps has dropped since the change, but the rest is working fine.